# simulating memfd_create on Linux 2.6

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I'm backporting a piece of code that uses a virtual memory trick involving a file descriptor that gets passed to `mmap`, but doesn't have a mount point. Having the physical file would be an unnecessary overhead in this application. The original code uses `memfd_create` which is great.

Since Linux 2.6 doesn't have `memfd_create` or the `O_TMPFILE` flag for `open`, I'm currently creating a file with `mkstemp` and then unlinking it without closing it first. This works, but it doesn't please me at all.

Is there a better way to get a file descriptor for `mmap` purposes without ever touching the file system in 2.6?

Before somebody says "XY problem," what I really need is two different virtual memory addresses to the same data in memory. This is implemented by `mmap`'ing the same anonymous file to two different addresses. Any other "Y" to my "X" also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I'd use [`shm_open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html)+[`shm_unlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_unlink.3.html), to put the backing file on tmpfs.

Comment: @NominalAnimal good point

Comment: You might also be able to achieve the same by first mapping anonymous shared pages, then creating a mapping to `/proc/self/mem` at an offset matching the address of the first mapping.. however, I'm not certain if `/proc/self/mem` is memory-mappable, or only accessible via non-mapped I/O. It should be easy to check, though. Personally, I'd use `shm_open()` and `shm_unlink()` myself; it should also be quite portable, too.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with it on Monday, but I don't think I mind the shm descriptor at all. I feel silly for not thinking of it myself. Do you want to post an answer rather than a comment so it can be accepted? (:

Comment: I'd rather you write an answer on your findings, after you've played with it, as this is something others too might encounter. (To write an answer, I would need to write a test program and verify its behaviour, to prove (mostly to myself) that I know what I am talking about. If you'll play with it anyway, why duplicate the work? It's the findings that matter.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Afair Linux documentation on `/proc/self/mem` said it was memory-mappable in the past, but this was removed because it was a source of many vulnerabilities.

Comment: @xcvii What is the problem with your current approach? `shm_open` will be equivalent as on Linux it just creates a file under `/dev/shm` which is `tmpfs`.

Comment: @Ivan No, the shared memory approach sounds good, I just got bogged down trying to get rid of the `unlink`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I considered two approaches:

1. Creating my temporary under `/dev/shm/` rather than `/tmp/`
2. Using `shm_open` to get a file descriptor.

Although irrelevant to the specific problem at hand, `/dev/shm/` is not guaranteed to exist on all distributions, so #2 felt more correct to me.

In order to not have to worry about unique names of the shared memory objects, I just generate UUIDs.

I think I'm happy with this.

Shout out to @NominalAnimal.